# How to build application with python and C# in Visual studio

Tags: python, c#

I want to build an application designed in C# forms Visual studio to get user input and want to process user input using python code? In python code, it has different methods to execute for each user input. I used simply for loops for that in python code.
How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

C# and Python are not compatible in that way. C# runs on .NET platform and Python runs in an interpreter written in C. You could try using [PythonSharp](https://github.com/ajlopez/PythonSharp), but it will be far from ideal (it's an old project). You could also write the whole application in Python with GUI toolkits. Most popular ones I know of are Tkinter and PyQT.

Edit: another project you might be interested in is [IronPython](https://ironpython.net/).

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to make python gui application.